# PHP- synchronization between online and offline database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have created a web application Hosted on godaddy.Sometimes I may not have internet connection so the same web application which also running on localhost server on my computer.I have to synchronization mysql database between online(godaddy) and offline. Is it possible to do like that ? Please give me any solution....

Comment: The only good solution is replication but unless you have root access on your Godaddy service, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: If you plan to have updates done on both sides, there's no reasonable alternative but if you only want to play with a copy of the database while offline, you can extract it with `mysqldump`.